# onSensorChanged check if the mobile is in an horizontal position (no landscape)

Tags: android, android-sensors

I need to check if the mobile goes to the horizontal position (no landscape, I mean like you place it on the table).

I know I have to use "SensorEventListener" interface and the "onSensorChanged" event, but I am not able to get an example to howto check the mobile position.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float[] values = event.values;
    float x = values[0];
    float y = values[1];
    float z = values[2];
    float norm =(float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);

    // Normalize the accelerometer vector
    x = (x / norm);
    y = (y / norm);
    z = (z / norm);
    int inclination = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(z)));

    if (inclination < 25 || inclination > 155)
    {
        // device is horiontal
        Toast.makeText(this,"device horiontal !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work like a charm, the only thing is that the event is called many times.

Comment: Yes, sensors should work like that. You can set an interval (predefined) when you register or add a timer to listen to